# Associate multiple tables with a single table

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I have a RDBMS database and I need to associate a column in a new table to multiple other existing tables whose schema can't be changed.

The new table looks something like this,

```
UUID(pk)   PartId(pk) Somecolumn1 SomeColumn2
asdf56das  0001       val1        val2
u44ighhuh  0002       val3        val4
u44ighhuh  0003       val5        val6
```

I want to associate UUID column with data from other tables.

One method is to add a XML column to this new table which would store the associations as,

```
<tablename><pkcolumn1>value</pkcolumn1> 
<pkcolumn2>value2</pkcolumn2>...........<pkcolumnN>valueN</pkcolumnN> 
</tablename>
```

With this approach there is some performance cost involved in creating and parsing XML.

One other way is to have a new "Mapping table" which will map the new table with the other existing table that I am trying to establish an association with.

Are there any other ways we can solve this?

Comment: In a relational database *tables* represent relation(ship)s/associations. ("Relationship" unfortunately is also ubiquitously incorrectly used to mean FK.) Add a table with a uuid etc from that table & whatever you want to record such a subrow is associated with in whatever way, for each such relation(ship)/association. *Normalization* tells you whether you can/should combine tables. Time to read a book on information modeling, the relational model & database design.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Answer (score 0):

A Foreign Key can have multiple columns.  So there's no reason you can't just use for each other_table either

1) A Foreign Key on new_table to other_table.

Or,

2) A new linking table with Foreign Keys to both new_table and other_table

With a linking table you can make the relationship 1-to-many, many-to-1 or many-to-many by declaring appropriate unique constraints.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For Approach 1 -  The schema of the "other table" cant be changed to accommodate a FK. Approach 2 - The "other table" can be many tables and not just one, with varying count of PK's(composite key). If we have a N "other tables" we would need N "Mapping tables"

Comment: @Suresh that's when you use a linking table with a 1-to-1 relationship to the "other table".